# Unlock Button Not Working within xRDP session

Tags: ubuntu, server, printing, permissions, xrdp

My Specific Error is this
"Unlock to Add Printers and Change Settings Some settings must be unlocked before they can be changed."
and the unlock button is not grayed out but it is not clickable. If I remember correctly it was grayed out before applying these fixes.

Ubuntu version: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Windowing: X11
GNOME VERSION: 42.5

I have created these files in 50-local.d "**45-allow-colord.pkla  46-allow-update-repo.pkla  46-user-admin.pkla**", With the corresponding scripts I found on this website, and others in an attempt to give my xRDP sessions full privileges and remove errors having to enter in the password multiple times upon login. I have also tried adding the user (myself) to adm and sudo groups. I have searched for hours on several search engines on how to get the unlock button to work in an xRDP session to work so that I can set up my R710 with a Cannon MG 2522 Printer as a home print server. So I can store sensitive or sentimental files, print from any computer, scan directly onto the server, and use the server with VM's for Cyber Security Practice.

This is what I put for each script respectively.

```
`[Allow Colord all Users]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.color-manager.create-device;org.freedesktop.color-manager.create-            profile;org.freedesktop.color-manager.delete-device;org.freedesktop.color-manager.delete-        profile;org.freedesktop.color-manager.modify-device;org.freedesktop.color-manager.modify-profile
ResultAny=no
ResultInactive=no
ResultActive=yes`


`[Allow Package Management all Users]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.packagekit.system-sources-refresh
ResultAny=yes
ResultInactive=yes
ResultActive=yes`

`[Allow Users administration]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.gnome-controlcenter.users-account.policy  
ResultAny=no 
ResultInactive=yes
ResultActive=yes`
```

This is how I attempted to add myself as a user to the adm and sudo groups

```
`sudo usermod -a -G adm <username>`
`sudo usermod -a -G sudo <username>`
```

I was looking at the post by gregswitft that mentioned this

"The first answer didn't work for me on Fedora and so I found this document.

Adding this to /etc/polkit-1/rules.d/90-printer-admin.rules worked immediately, didn't even have to close and reopen the control panel."

```
`polkit.addRule(function(action, subject) {
    if (/^org\.opensuse\.cupspkhelper\.mechanism\./.test(action.id) &&
        subject.isInGroup("lp")) {
            return polkit.Result.YES;
    }
});`
```

but I do not have a rules.d directory. Maybe I should add it to the directory I added the other .pkla files. I also found an article mentioning the sesman.ini Maybe I have to allow login as root. I also tried finding a suitable print driver for the MG2522 but perhaps that I Installed gutenberg print will suffice as long as I can get past this. The button still will not work, after several restarts and updates throughout implementing possible solutions.

Comment: Is this just not possible through RDP?